# What is the difference between matrix_basis and matrix_world?

Tags: python, documentation, matrix

I know it is a bad question sorry but I haven't found any information about these matrices expect in the blender documentations.

The docs say that matrix_basis is:

> Matrix access to location, rotation and scale (including deltas),
>   before constraints and parenting are applied.

So if not related to any parent, is it the same as matrix_world ?

Comment: The mathviz (currently dead wiki link) addon is a  a perfect way to experiment. Enable addon and type `MW = C.object.matrix_world` into python console and  a rep'n of matrix is drawn in 3d view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`matrix_basis` is the 'input' matrix, so it's the thing that you set as the 3D artist, so it's relative to the object's parent. `matrix_world` is the 'evaluated' matrix, so it basically is `matrix_basis` with all the constraints applied and is multiplied by all the parent matrices (so it's in world coordinates).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But now the question is then what is matrix_local ? Because what you said for the matrix_basis I thought it is the local.

Comment: The API documentation actually describes the difference: "Only takes into account ‘Object’ parenting"